# PostgreSQL 9.5 query elegant like spreadsheet

Tags: sql, postgresql

**There are some new (pg9.X) way to express a query with a function that depends on two adjacent rows?** Can use LATERAL?

Example:

```
ID   VAL   DIFF    NOTES
11   6     3       9-6=3
12   9     21      30-9=21
13   30    30      no row to subtract
```

How to express `DIFF(i) = VAL(i-1)-VAL(i)` with an elegant `SELECT`? 
PS: suppose `ORDER BY "ID"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) like [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) (which have been available since Postgres 8.4)

```
select id, 
       val, 
       lead(val) over (order by id) - val as diff
from the_table
order by id;
```

lead() access the column value of the *next* row based on the `order by`. If there is no next row, the result is `null`, thus the result of the subtraction is also null for the last row.

**Edit**

If you want to use multiple window functions with the same window definition you can define this once and re-use it:

```
select id, 
       val, 
       lead(c1) over w - val as diff1, 
       lead(c2) over w - val as diff2
from the_table
window w as (order by id)
order by id;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a complex query with a long ORDER BY, and need more than one `lead()` ... There are a way to omit at `over` the  `(order by id)`, and say "`over` same `order by` than this query"?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: if you have multiple window functions you can declare the window once. See my edit